# Setting focus points in HTML for screen readers

Tags: html, accessibility, html-lists, voiceover

I was wondering if its possible to set specific areas for a screen reader to focus on in HTML content.

I have a list that is something like the following:

```
<ol>
  <li>
    <div class="duration">
      <time>10:00</time>
      <span>to</span>
      <time>11:00</time>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
      <span>CA267 Lecture</span>
      <span>Software Testing</span>
      <span>Location: QG27</span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

When I bring a screen reader(in my case voice over) over the list item it starts off with 10:00 then I have to press ctrl+alt+left arrow key to move onto "to" and then again to move onto 11:00 and so on so forth.

I was wondering is there a way to group the elements so that the screen reader focuses on the `<li>` tag and just reads out everything in it accordingly?

I have tried setting a tabindex it somewhat works but requires the screen reader user to use the tab key for navigation rather than its built in shortcut keys.

Comment: The key combo you mentioned reads the next word. You would want to use down arrow, L, or P.

Comment: Hi Ryan! I tried down arrow and it beeps at me, as does L. P reads 10:00. If I leave voice over on focus of the `<ol>` for awhile it gives control+alt+leftarrow and control+alt+rightarrow as the only options

Comment: Sorry Duffy, my specialty isn't VO, but I would say what you're dhoing isn't valid code. Why aren't youu using a table?

Comment: I wouldn't of considered it tabular data.

Comment: I would say it is, times, locations, course names all related, from the sample.

Answer (score 0):

ARIA attributes can do that, but the spec isn't finished, kind of confusing (at least to me), and screen reader support is not optimal. i'm thinking maybe you could apply `aria-labelledby` or `aria-describedby`, but both solutions i'm looking at in mdn would require altering your markup. it looks like `aria-labelledby` is achievable by simply adding some ids to your `ol` and then the `aria-labelledby` element on the `div`s. you can check it out here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-labelledby_attribute

Comment: Screen reader support for ARIA is pretty decent. It is everything else, both AT-wise and non, that is lacking support. Unless you can provide some sample code, I would say `labelledby` is not applicable here unless you have a `<p>` floating around that you wish to use to described the `<ol>`, even then `aria-describedby` probably should be used.

Comment: i'll be more specific: aria support in screen readers amongst varying browser/platforms. i said it was confusing, and even moreso without seeing the whole document. moreover, the linked i gave shows the example i'm thinking of, it's the first one. i also said it would be tough without changing his markup.

Comment: Thank you! Defiantly a step in the right direction. Haven't got it fully working but I am getting somewhere. Will paste back a code example if I get it.

Comment: Setting role=menuitem on the li does exactly what I want. Calling it a menuitem isn't exactly valid though.